Debian live system cannot boot with manually installed grub
I'm creating a debian live system on a USB drive with a customized filesystem.squashfs.
I installed grub with grub-install --boot-directory=/media/main/linux-live/boot/grub --efi-directory=/media/main/linux-live /dev/sda, sda is my USB drive.
Then I wrote grub.cfg:
menuentry "Live" {
    linux   /live/vmlinuz boot=live
    initrd  /live/initrd.img
}

filesystem.squashfs, initrd.img and vmlinuz have been put into the live directory.
Then I successfully booted into my live system.
However, After I renamed the directory live to livex and correspondingly modified the grub.cfg, I received Kernel Panic while booting the live system.
Why I cannot change the directory name, thanks.
